# Map from int to class

Tags: java, inria-spoon

I want to create objects of different classes based on user input, i.e. the user will tell which class's object to create. I have something like this :

`launcher.addProcessor((Processor) new SerializableFieldProcessor(projectKey));`

Now I have other processors and want the user to give an integer input and depending on that, the respective processor's object to be created. A straightforward way is to use switch cases, but later on I'm going to have more than 50 or 100 separate processors. Is there a way to do this with a map or something similar? Something like this :

```
Map<int,Processor> mymap;
//initialize mymap;
int x= user_input;
launcher.addProcessor((Processor) new mymap[x]);
```

Comment: You can not use the primitive `int` as a key for a map, but there is an object representation `Integer` whhich you can use instead. So you only have to box the userinput. E.g: `Integer userIn = Integer.valueOf(<sourceOfInput>)`.

Comment: you should try `Map<Integer, Processor>` and pre-initialize the `map` first and then just return the `instance`.

Comment: A `common` interface should help you, if you will use the `Processor` in a consistent way.

Comment: Which type of map are you using? Because for `java.util.Map` the access syntax `mymap[x]` is invalid.

Comment: @L.Spillner  Sorry C++ habits :)

Comment: @AshutoshVerma So we are talking about plain old Java. Good. So you want to create Objects based on the input from the user am I right?

Comment: Yes. I have found the solution using Reflection and posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution you might want to consider is as follows:

```
Map<Integer, Class<? extends Processor>> map = new HashMap<>();
// Integer.valueOf(x) used to prevent autoboxin just a matter of opinion.
map.put( Integer.valueOf( 0 ), MyProcessor.class );

Processor chosen = map.get( userIn ).getConstructor( String.class ).newInstance( projectKey );

launcher.addProcessor(chosen);
```

It is basically the same but the difference is that the returned object is of the type `Processor` and the class does definitly exist. When you are using a String and `Class.forName(...)` there are two additional exceptions that may be thrown. First the `ClassNotFoundException` which will be thrown if the `Class.forName()` method did not find the class for the given name. The 2nd additional exception is the `ClassCastException` which will be thrown if the created object is not an implementation or subclass of `Processor`.

---

**Explanation:**

We are using a map with an `Integer` as our key and a `Class<? extends Processor>` as our value. A `Class<T>` object can be considered as an object representation of the corresponding .class file (technically incorrect but for the sake of simplicity we assume it is that way). What does `<? extends Processor>` mean in concrete? It means that the map will only allow values of Classes which are an implementation or a subtype of `Processor`. Doing so eliminates the thread of a `ClassCastException` because if we can only store classes which extend Processor we can only retrieve classes which can be casted to an `Processor` without any issues or even the thread of one.

---

**Note:** I chained the instantiation process which usually is a bad idea in a productive environment but it shortens the code quite a lot and there is no need to further explain it since you use the exact same approach in your own answer.

Comment: Much better. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Lews Therin. I have found a solution using Java Reflection.

```
 Map<Integer,String > rule=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
 rule.put(1948,"SerializableFieldProcessor");

 Class<?> processor = Class.forName(rule.get(1948));
 Constructor<?> cons = processor.getConstructor(String.class);
 Object object = cons.newInstance(projectKey);
 launcher.addProcessor( (Processor)object);
```

Comment: I just remembered a usecase where the approach using `Class.forName(...)` is way more useful than my approach. Consider you want to add a new `Processor` to the application without recompiling the entire code. Then you can add the compiled .class and create some kind of config file containing all names of available `Processors`, read and store all of them in the map. So in case of safety my approach can be considered more usefull but this answer definitly wins when it comes to a flexible and extendable structure of your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo { }
public class Bar { }

private Object userChosenClass(Int userInput) { 
    if (userInput == 0) {
       return new Foo();
    } else if (userInput == 1) {
       return new Bar();
    } else {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Or, you can have a map of Ints -> Classes and then query the map to get the corresponding class for the given input Int. For instance:

```
public class UserClassSelector {
    private Map<Int, Class> map;

    public UserClassSelector() {
        map = new Map<Int, Class>();
    }

    public Void addMapping(Int fromInt, Class toClass) {
        map[fromInt] = toClass;
    }

    public Object instantiateFromMap(Int forInt) {
        if (map[forInt] != null) {
            return new map[forInt]();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to avoid exactly this.. is reflection a possibility?

Comment: this is even `worse` than the OP's idea using `switch`

Comment: Hi. I've already considered this and mentioned in the question. The thing is I'm going to have 100 different classes in my project and it won't be nice to write 100 if statements

Comment: Ok your edit seems helpful. If it works, then that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Well, I write Kotlin day to day, so there may be a compile issue (if I got some syntax wrong) but the edit is the general gist. Would appreciate if you could upvote the answer as I just lost a load of rep for my first answer attempt).

Comment: @LewsTherin Thank you. I have found a solution using reflection. I'll post it as an answer.